# class inheritance activity -> vote

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, android-activity

I have two classes, one for handling *activities* (e.g. `x liked y`, `z commented on y`) and one for *votes* (`up`, `down`, sort of like thumbs up, down).

Should i see class `vote` as a subset of `activity` as it is an *activity*?  Or should I keep them separate?

**why do I have this problem?**

My brain is saying: Keep it all seperate! The only things I think should be in another class, is database, and the session class.
But my lazy programmer hands think I should just make voting a subactivity? But 'activity' is handling the posting/displaying of activities.

Is my perception of OOP wrong? What would be a solid (future-proof) way to tackle this?

Comment: I guess that depends of what kind  of vote it is. It is more in the way "x voted up for y"? If so, I think yes, you could make vote a sub-activity and add some properties to vote (like the up, down and so on). Just in my opinion.

Comment: it would come out as : (user x) (dis)liked (title of content y)

Comment: And, in the case x liked y, it is exactly, x liked content of y?

Comment: Solid is here: http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, OOP is a paradigm that should help you design, not confuse. OOP isn't the best answer to the meaning of life and everything.

If your `Vote` really **IS AN** `Activity` then it should have inherited all its functionality and be able to use it.

I understand from your problem that it does not.

So, if they do have some similar concepts, you could redefine your `Activity`.
Make a base class called `BaseActivity` which has the basic common stuff, and let them both inherit that.

Comment: the class activity makes me able to post, edit, delete and list all activity. 

Vote handles votes (a seperate database) and makes the inserts, which is of course seperate of activities.